# Не работает dict(zip()) в Python

Tags: python, zip, dict

Есть два списка:

```
local = [('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/1')]
remote = [('R1', 'Eth0/1'), ('R2', 'Eth0/2'), ('R3', 'Eth0/3'), ('R6', 'Eth0/5')]
```

При выполнении команды `dict(zip(remote, local))` выдает верный словарь:

```
{('R1', 'Eth0/1'): ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'),
 ('R2', 'Eth0/2'): ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'),
 ('R3', 'Eth0/3'): ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'),
 ('R6', 'Eth0/5'): ('SW1', 'Eth0/1')}
```

А когда ввожу `dict(zip(local, remote))` почему-то отсекает первые два элемента:

```
{('SW1', 'Eth0/0'): ('R3', 'Eth0/3'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/1'): ('R6', 'Eth0/5')}
```

В чем проблема? Как это исправить?

Comment: Дело в том что ключом может быть только уникальные значения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

может потому что из

```
('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/1')
```

только

```
('SW1', 'Eth0/0'), ('SW1', 'Eth0/1')
```

уникальны

словарь же содержит уникальные ключи

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо!